# How does printf for float does not print the correct value for floating point

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

So i have been trying to make my own printf and now i stuck at %f.
The problem i have is i don't know what printf does in the background when i give it a float number like: `f = 1.4769996` it print 1.477000.
but when i give it `f = 1.4759995` it print the value 1.475999

```c
float f = 1.4769996;
printf("%f\n", f); // 1.477000

f = 1.4759995;
printf("%f\n", f); // 1.475999
```

what i thought of is that printf see the 5 at last and it adds one but not working in the second example.

What is the logic behind this floating point ?

Comment: so what i understand is that i should consider using rounding functions for this probllem ?

Comment: `printf` does not "see" a 5. It only sees ones and zeros. If you want to round the printout, read the documentation for printf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C implementation likely uses the IEEE-754 binary32 and binary64 formats for `float` and `double`. Given this, `float f = 1.4769996;` results in setting `f` to 1.47699964046478271484375, and `f = 1.4759995;` results in setting `f` to 1.47599947452545166015625.

Then it is easy to see that rounding **1.476999**64046478271484375 to six digits after the decimal point results in 1.477000 (because the next digit is 6, so we round up), and rounding **1.475999**47452545166015625 to six digits after the decimal point results in 1.475999 (because the next digit is 4, so we round down).

When working with floating-point numbers, it is important to understand each floating-point value represents one number **exactly** (unless it is a Not a Number [NaN] encoding). When you write `1.4769996` in source code, it is converted to a value representable in `double`. When you assign it to a `float`, it is converted to a value representable in `float`. Operations on the floating-point object behave as if the object have exactly the value it represents, not as if its value is the numeral you wrote in source code.

To provide some further details, the C standard requires (in C 2018 7.21.6.1 13) that formatting with `f` be correctly rounded if the number of digits requested is at most `DECIMAL_DIG`. `DECIMAL_DIG` is the number of decimal digits in the widest floating-point format the implementation supports such that converting any number in that format to a numeral with `DECIMAL_DIG` significant decimal digits and back to the floating-point format yields the original value (5.2.4.2.2 12). `DECIMAL_DIG` must be at least 10. If more than `DECIMAL_DIG` digits are requested, the C standard allows some leeway in rounding. However, high-quality C implementations will round correctly as specified by IEEE-754 (to the nearest number with the requested number of digits, with ties favoring an even low digit).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to write your own `printf`, and if you are stuck on `%f`, there are three or four things you need to know:

1. When a "varargs" function like `printf` is called, arguments of type `float` are always implicitly promoted to type `double`.  So when you've seen `%f` in the format string, and you're using `va_arg()` to pluck the next argument from the list, you'll want to pluck an argument of type `double`, not `float`.  (This also means that you have just one case to handle, not two.  Inside `printf`, you don't have to worry about handling type `float` at all.)
2. Printing the whole-number part of a `double` is easy; it's more or less the same problem as printing an `int`, which I'm guessing you've already figured out, if you've got `%d` working.  And to do a straightforward, simpleminded job of printing the fractional part, it usually works pretty well to just repeatedly multiply by 10.  That is, if you're trying to print `123.456`, and you've already got the `123` part taken care of, you can then proceed to print the rest by taking the fractional part `0.456`, multiplying by 10 to get `4.56` then truncating to get `4`, then taking the new fractional part `0.56` and repeating.
3. There is no such number as `1.4769996`.  (There's no such number as the `123.456` I was just using, either.)  When we write numbers like `1.4769996` and `123.456` we're thinking about decimal fractions, but most computers (including the one you're using) use *binary* fractions internally, and you can't represent decimal fractions like `1.4769996` and `123.456` exactly in binary, so the actual numbers are always a little bit different than you expect, which is why you often get slight "roundoff error", or extra 999's at the end when you expected 000.
4. Doing a proper job on this stuff is really, really hard.  If you're trying to write your own `printf`, and you've gotten to `%f`, and if you can get it working pretty well most of the time, consider yourself lucky, and call it a day.  Don't get bogged down on the last digit -- or if you're bound and determined to get the last digit right in every case (which is certainly a noble goal), do some research and set aside some time, because you're going to be working at it for a while.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, very helpful. i am at the part 4 and yes it is really hard to do, i will try my best :D